# convert string to yyyy-dd-mm date object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs, sails.js

I am getting fromdate and todate fields from HTML.
fromdate='2020-07-30'.
my db is having a field idate as 2020-07-30. Now i want to compare both of them.
so i am using the following code:

```
 var dashboard2= await Incident.find({type:'somestring',username:region,idate:{'>=':new Date(fromdate),'<=':new Date(todate)}})
```

if my fromdate is '2020-07-30'. But its not retrieving record with idate: 2020-07-30. if my fromdate is '2020-07-29' only then the record with  idate: 2020-07-30 is being retrieved.

Here fromdate is a string. idate is a dateobject.

I dont know where i am going wrong. Please correct me?

Based on the suggestion I have changed my code like this:

```
function yyyyddmmFormatter(date) {
  var dateDiv = date.split('-');
  console.log(dateDiv);
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(dateDiv[2]);
  date.setMonth(dateDiv[1]-1);
  date.setFullYear(dateDiv[0]); // -- since it starts from 0

  return date;
}
```

my input fromdate string is "2020-07-16". Output I got is 2020-07-16T01:11:05.910Z. I want to get rid off timezone from the returned o/p. is that possible?

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: I'm thinking timezones

Comment: I am using mongo dB through sails

Answer (score 0):

you should update your fromdate as well, because passing fromdate a fix date will not update it to the new date.

Comment: What does this mean?

Comment: I didn't understand what u are saying.. Fromdate is user input.

Comment: if you pass a fixed from date into idate, it will not allow idate to update to a new date, fromdate should be a correct and updated info, i mean check the code for fromdate... still confused then send me your fromdate code please.

Comment: My fromdate field is var fromdate=req.body.fromdate.. I am getting it from html. Its a date field user input

Comment: are you using body parser to get the data from the file? if this is plain html try to use ejs i prefer ejs files over plain html files make sure the code for bodyparser is extended to true.

Comment: I am using ejs files.  urlencoded: bodyParser.urlencoded({
    limit: maxUploadOptions.limit,
    extended: true
  }),.. This is part of my http.js code.

Comment: seems fine, when you are letting the person enter the date for you, is it in the right format?? check the format of data and try to put validations to it if possible, if not happening yet then please send a complete snippet of the code you are trying so that we may check for some other error.

Answer (score 0):

Any formatting related to the date you can use the `moment` module.

Edited:
this will convert string to object of date.

```
function yyyyddmmFormatter(date) {
  var dateDiv = date.split('-');
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(dateDiv[0]);
  date.setMonth(dateDiv[1]--); // -- since it starts from 0
  date.setFullYear(dateDiv[2]);

  return date;
};

function yyyyddmmFormatterWithTime(date) {
  var dateDiv = date.split('-');
  var date = new Date();
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); // to reset time
  date.setDate(dateDiv[0]);
  date.setMonth(dateDiv[1]--); // -- since it starts from 0
  date.setFullYear(dateDiv[2]); 

  return date;
};

var date = yyyyddmmFormatter("2020-07-30");
var dateWithTime = yyyyddmmFormatterWithTime("2020-07-30");
```

Comment: This doesn’t address the issue. And according to the tags they’re already using moment.

Comment: I used moment also.. But no use. I need a date object for my fromdate string.

Comment: Hi.. I tried this...function yyyyddmmFormatter(date) {
  var dateDiv = date.split('-');
  console.log(dateDiv);
  var date = new Date();
  date.setDate(dateDiv[2]);
  date.setMonth(dateDiv[1]-1);
  date.setFullYear(dateDiv[0]); // -- since it starts from 0

  return date;
};   My input is '2020-07-16' and my returned date is  2020-07-16T01:11:05.910Z.. How can I get rid off timezone? :(

Comment: you can use properties of date like date.toLocaleString();

Answer (score 0):

I just used this while storing and while retrieving. This helped me solve my problem. Just simple solution:
while retrieving:

```
var fdate=new date(fromdate);
```

while storing dates :

```
var date1= new Date(pdate);
```

This converted both dates to same format.